# Whats the difference between the hoverbikes?

Tags: starbound

There are 3 Hoverbikes for sale at Penguin Pete's Vehicle lot:

[image: Totally legit pirate business]

Apart from color and price is there any difference between the bikes ? 4k pixels seems like bit much for a different color.

Comment: Green is the best colour, 4k pixels doesnt seem like much for the best colour..

Comment: Perhaps someone can buy all three and take them all for a spin. Different damage levels, maybe? Who knows, pure speculation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like it really is purely cosmetic, according to a post in [this thread](http://community.playstarbound.com/threads/hoverbike-colors.104026/):

> Digging through the files and it looks like it's all just aesthetics, every hoverbike seems to have the same stats.